# Ionic Native tried accessing the GoogleMaps plugin but it's not installed

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently trying to implement GoogleMaps through ionic. I am a total beginner, so please beware! I am getting an error:

```
console.warn: Native: tried accessing the GoogleMaps plugin but it's not installed.
```

whenever I run

```
ionic cordova build ios
ionic cordova emulate ios -lc
```

My code within `home.ts` looks as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, LatLng } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public geolocation: Geolocation, private googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {
    console.log("Home page creator loaded");
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit loaded");

    let mapEle = document.getElementById('map');
    let location = new LatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);
    let mapOpt = {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8,
    };

    this.map = this.googleMaps.create(mapEle, mapOpt);
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
      console.log("Map seems ready!");
    });
  }
}
```

Mostly adapted to what the ionic-native GoogleMaps tutorial suggests. I have repeated uninstall and installed the ionic-native [google-maps plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) again, but it just doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @DaveTheAI Did you added plugin to the app module as specified here - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module

Comment: @Gandhi, yes I did... my app.module.ts includes:

import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
 ...
providers: [ 
...
GoogleMaps,
    GoogleMap,
...
]
...

Comment: @Gandhi i m not an expert in Ionic as i dont have hands on in it.. but the plugin code should be invoked inside platform ready event as far as i know.. is that taken care?

Comment: Are you using the ionic preview app to test your app?

Comment: @Gandhi, do you mean invoking the code from within `platform.ready().then(() => {...}`?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, no I'm not, is this the website? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app also, what are the advantages to emulating ios over terminal?

Comment: @DaveTheAI you are right.. Invoking inside device ready event?

Comment: I was asking because it probably doesn't work inside the preview app and people usually use that app to test, but if you are not using it then the problem is something else

Answer (score -1):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.loadMap();
  });
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.